# Show string with html tags in Stimulsoft js report

Tags: c#, html, json, report, stimulsoft

I have an report using Stimulsoft js report, that It's data source is Json data, one of properties in this Json object, sometimes taged with html tagsm but when rendering this Json object, I occurred this Exception:

Connection 'Mail': After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: w. Path '[0].TextBody', line 29, position 86.

```
[
        {
            "Subject": "Úáí",
            "SenderName": "ÏÑíÇÝÊ ˜ääÏÇä",
            "ReceiversName": "ÏÑíÇÝÊ",
            "CcReceiversName": "ãåã",
            "SentDate": "1393-03-03",
            "Status":"1",
            "HasAttachment":true,
            "Priority":"1",
            "Privacy":"1",
            "SentDateString":"ÏíÑæÒ",
            "IsForward":true,
            "IsReplied":true,
            "InboxId":"97002F44-BDC2-483D-A6CC-51A6479FB272",
            "ReferenceNumber":"1",
            "RefrenceDate":"1393-03-03",
            "ReferenceHasNote":true,
            "Labels":"test",
            "IsRead":true,
            "IsStarred":true,
            "IsImportant":true,
            "IsInInbox":true,
            "PriorityTitle":"ãåã",
            "PrivacyTitle":"ÓÑí",
            "RefrenceId":"97002F44-BDC2-483D-A6CC-51A6479FB272",
            "ReplyDeadLine":"1393-03-03",
            "HasPrevious":true,
            "TextBody": "<p><span style=\"background-color:rgb(231, 231, 231); color:rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family:fonixbyekan; font-size:14px\">مژده وصل تو کو کز سر جان بر خیزم&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; طایر قدسم و از دام جهان برخیزم</span><br />\n<span style=\"background-color:rgb(231, 231, 231); color:rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family:fonixbyekan; font-size:14px\">بوفای تو که گر بنده خویشم خوانی&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; از سر خواجگی کون و مکان برخیزم</span><br />\n<span style=\"background-color:rgb(231, 231, 231); color:rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family:fonixbyekan; font-size:14px\">یا رب از ابر هدایت برسان بارانی</span></p>\n"

        }
    ]
```

Comment: This JSON data works great. You could test it on http://js.stimulsoft.com/

Comment: @HighAley, Thanks but TextBody Could' not be Parsed. Since It tagged with Html tags

Comment: What version of Stimulsoft Reports.JS do you use? Try to download [the latest build](http://example.com/)

Comment: @HighAley , Latest Version 2015

Comment: There is a 2015.3 build with many improvements.